# jQuery prepend() and Append() not working, what is wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jquery

```js
var proQty = $(".quantitybox");
proQty.prepend('<span class="dec changebtn">-</span>');
proQty.append('<span class="inc changebtn">+</span>');
proQty.on('click', '.changebtn', function () {
```

My HTML code

```html
<div class="cart-modal-price">
    <p>Fruits</p>
    <p>Price: Ksh. 120/-</p>
    <input type="number" class="quantitybox" placeholder="1">
</div>
```

Comment: And the question/problem (_"not working"_ is no meaningful description) is?

Comment: the prepends doesnt show up on the html

Comment: _"The `.prepend()` method inserts the specified content as the first child of each element in the jQuery collection"_, _"The `.append()` method inserts the specified content as the last child of each element in the jQuery collection"_ - An `<input />` element has no children

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```js
var proQty = $(".quantitybox");
proQty.prepend('<span class="dec changebtn">-</span>');
proQty.append('<span class="inc changebtn">+</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

<div class="cart-modal-price">
    <p>Fruits</p>
    <p>Price: Ksh. 120/-</p>
    <span class="quantitybox"><input type="number" placeholder="1"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked thanks. Why do you think mine failed. I just dont understand or was it appending it inside the input?

Comment: hey, can you please approve my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for `before()` and `after()`

```js
var proQty = $(".quantitybox");
proQty.before('<span class="dec changebtn">-</span>');
proQty.after('<span class="inc changebtn">+</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart-modal-price">
  <p>Fruits</p>
  <p>Price: Ksh. 120/-</p>
  <input type="number" class="quantitybox" placeholder="1">
</div>
```

Comment: That would have been fine but I think there are a few challenges that I would face if I use this method

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't work because (as per [comment from Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63011765/jquery-prepend-and-append-not-working-what-is-wrong/63012963#comment111429621_63011765))

> "The `.prepend()` method inserts the specified content as the first child of each element in the jQuery collection", "The `.append()` method inserts the specified content as the last child of each element in the jQuery collection" - An `<input />` element has no children.

You should be using https://api.jquery.com/after/ & https://api.jquery.com/before/.

> **after** : Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

> **before** : Insert content, specified by the parameter, before each element in the set of matched elements.

```js
var proQty = $(".quantitybox");
proQty.before('<span class="dec changebtn">-</span>');
proQty.after('<span class="inc changebtn">+</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart-modal-price">
  <p>Fruits</p>
  <p>Price: Ksh. 120/-</p>
  <input type="number" class="quantitybox" placeholder="1" />
</div>
```

Comment: @Andreas Your comment completely descriptive and I can not find any better words so I used it here. I've mentioned link for your comment in answer. Thanks for comment.